# How to fix SQL server JSON_VALUE path has '-' error

Tags: sql, json, json-value

I'm trying to get values of fields in sql that is in JSON type. unfortunately path has '-' so that I get an error when I try to get the value.

```
field->** **{"Con":["AA"],"X-Location-Latitude":["55.06"]}
```

When I try to get json value with below query

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(field, '$.X-Location-Latitude') 
FROM table
```

I get this error

> Json path is not properly formatted unexpected character '-' is found

I also tried adding double quotes as

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(field, '$."X-Location-Latitude"') 
FROM table
```

and this returned NULL.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: *I also tried adding double quotes* - [Works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=275746f7a6e6ea4af6870a0ceb74afe9) - check your JSON truly contains a scalar value at that location

Comment: It has the value "X-Location-Latitude":["55.06"]

Comment: @Zeir have you tried brackets? ["X-Location-Latitude"]

Comment: `"[55]"` is a *completely* different thing to `["55"]`...

Comment: @CaiusJard yes noticed it thx to ur comment and edited right after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you originally posted:

```
field-> {"Con":"[AA]","X-Location-Latitude":"[55]"}
```

`"[55]"` is a single string of length 4; `'$."X-Location-Latitude"'` is correct for that single value.

---

I see now that you've changed it to:

```
{"Con":["AA"],"X-Location-Latitude":["55.06"]}
```

`["55.06"]` is a *completely different thing* (and not because of the `.06`); it's an **array of strings**, with one element `"55.06"`. This makes all the difference to JSON_VALUE

JSON_VALUE cannot be used with a path that selects an array; you'll have to nominate a single value in the array, for example:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(field, '$."X-Location-Latitude"[0]') FROM table
                                                 ^^^
                                          first array element
```

JSON_VALUE must be used with scalar (single value) properties, not collections/arrays(things enclosed in `[]`) or complex objects (things enclosed in `{}`)

[The fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#lax-mode-and-strict-mode) has a nice table about what happens when you try select various things with JSON_VALUE, in lax and strict mode

Answer (score 0):

Replacing **JSON_VALUE** with **JSON_QUERY** fixed my problem.

So below code works fine

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(field, '$."X-Location-Latitude"') FROM table
```

**Returns ["55.06"]**